# Unable to start kafka server (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

was trying to start kafka server and was ending up with the following error:-

```
(org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\vich0221\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:os.name=Windows 10 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:os.version=10.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:user.name=vignesh (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:user.home=C:\Users\vignesh (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO Client environment:user.dir=C:\kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/zookeeper/Watcher;Lorg/apache/zookeeper/client/ZKClientConfig;)V
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:117)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1948)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:431)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:456)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:191)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,934] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,950] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,950] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,950] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)
[2021-08-26 17:20:57,950] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

My Zookeeper was up and running

```
[2021-08-26 17:20:29,150] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with it. It was working earlier and I didn't touch any configuration file. I simply started the zookeeper and when trying to start kafka server it was throwing an error. I can see in the error near **java.compiler** it is set to **NA**. But I was able to detect java using `java -version` from cmd. Is this causing that error????

How to overcome this??

Comment: Are the zookeeper and kafka versions you are using compatible?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the zip from apache Kafka site https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.8.0/kafka_2.13-2.8.0.tgz. Actually, it was worked 2 hours earlier. Now it's not working

Comment: Do you have any zookeeper version anywhere in the classpath? Also check, if the zookeeper is in the classpath of the Kafka server.

Comment: I'm sorry, Where do I need to check that.

Comment: The `libs` folder in the kafka dir typically contains all the required libraries that Kafka uses.  I see the zookeeper version for your above url to be 3.5.9 from the name of the jar file in the `lib` folder. Check if you have anything different there (or) you have any other zookeeper jar file there.

Comment: You can also check the CLASSPATH using `echo $CLASSPATH`. I suppose that your kafka broker logs should also be containing the classpath printed, you may want to check there as well.

Comment: Yes, there are two jar files related to zookeeper (zookeeper-3.5.9 and zookeeper-jute-3.5.9)

Comment: In server log, I can see the following **environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13**

Comment: This is not the version for 2.8.0, search for corresponding jar file and possibly replace it with zookeeper-3.5.9.jar

Comment: In lib folder no zookeeper jar with version 3.4.13 . It was with version 3.5.9 but not sure why it is using 3.4.13

Comment: Thanks for your time @JavaTechnical . I'll replace the jar and will inform you if it is working fine

Comment: Even now, it is still the same. In class path I can see 3.5.9 but near environment:zookeeper.version= it was picking up 3.4.13

Comment: Dont use the `.bat` scripts to run Kafka on Windows https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same question, It is most likely that there are jar packages of other versions of zookeeper under your classpath. You can check by executing the `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties` command and then viewing the log. below is my log, I found the wrong zookeeper version: `/usr/local/hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar`

[my log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDvO3.png)